# bash while read loop fails with \ as line termination

Tags: bash

Input file:

```
$ cat list 
dog \
cat \
apple \
```

script:

```
while read line;do echo $line;done < list;
```

The Problem:
The above script prints nothing. Whereas using 'read -r' in place of read prints all lines.

My Question is..

Shouldn't the while loop run at least once in the above case(without -r) and print the first line of output ? Why the condition check fails on the first line itself ?

Comment: Check the output code. You can run `read <<< 'something ending in \'` by itself and then do `echo $?`. I suspect that allowing \ to escape the last newline makes `read` exit with an error because it's expecting more input when it hits EOF. Also, try removing the last backslash in the file and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

Since all newlines are escaped, and `read` reads till an unescaped newline, it reaches end-of-file without getting one. And, as `help read` says:

```
Exit Status:
The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out
(in which case it's greater than 128), a variable assignment error occurs,
or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

Note that `line` still contains the lines read so far:

```
$ while read line; do echo "$line"; done < foo; echo $line
dog cat apple
```

Comment: Glad to see my stupid theory I just made up is correct :)